# Not able to get pushnotification at iphone4s device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, notifications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have followed all the steps for implementing pushnotification using the raywenderlich tutorial but I'm getting an error while running this command:

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert XYZCert.pem -key XYZKey.pem


CONNECTED(00000003)
  depth=1 /C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated     
  by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C

**verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0**
---
Certificate chain
0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple Inc./OU=iTMS Engineering/CN=gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com
i:/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
1 s:/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
i:/O=Entrust.net/OU=www.entrust.net/CPS_2048 incorp. by ref. (limits liab.)/OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited/CN=Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple Inc./OU=iTMS Engineering/CN=gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
---
**No client certificate CA names sent**
---
SSL handshake has read 2731 bytes and written 2160 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
Protocol : TLSv1
Cipher : AES256-SHA
Session-ID:
Session-ID-ctx:
Master-Key: CE7F8C43CF32CC6E2F9C81E8898E89EAEC8B4E1110B7AA50C0FDABB3ED628A0623C7905B956E6F28A0E85A4AECA9986B
Key-Arg : None
Start Time: 1339390594
Timeout : 300 (sec)
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
**read:errno=54**
```

I am able to get the device token and while using php code to send notification it is showing:

```
Connected to APNS  
Message successfully delivered
```

But I'm still not receiving notifications on iphone4s.

With every profile I'm getting the same device token.

So totally stuck with notification. How to resolve this?

Comment: Your php-script is on your mac or on a server? If it is on your local mac, then make sure that both your devices (mac and ipad/iphone) are connected to the same wireless network

Comment: Make sure your router has the port 2195 forwarded through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does APNS return error-response packet to you?

if your token is invalid or the notification malformed, APNS will return the error-response.